# Grant column-based access in a library - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, user, access

I'd like to grant user permissions to specific documents defined for a given project type. Unfortunately, all documents are lumped into a single Shared Documents library, categorized by a column header called "Project."

I'd like to grant users permissions to the Shared Documents library, but narrow contribute read/write access only to documents with Project category `x`, and they are barred from write/access to all other documents.

[image]

How is this done at the column level per library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instead, use folders. You can break out the column values into respective folders and apply uninherited permissions to each folder. That way you will have a true security level for each "column"--which is now a folder. You can thus delete the column from the list, once all the data has been moved into their own folders.

EDIT:
Views will display and hide information based what you want in a view. It will display the columns you want, and filter in and out items that you care to display. It is only a view of the content, not the actual raw data. Much like a SQL query, others have the ability to read more than what the query is if they have access to it, but they may set up their own views, or if they know what they are looking for they can find it. Search and Explorer View can be an ally in this process. Be wary of using views as a security measure, as they are only meant to focus on data that is useful. If security of those documents are not an issue, views are the perfect way to focus on the data they need. They will see all the views available to them.

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to break documents into separate folders, and could just bar access to the document through access permissions at the document library level.

Comment: There are ways to hide documents or have separate views that filter out, but those aren't true security levels, just like how audience targeting does not prevent users from finding content, only hides it from initial view.

Comment: @Mike: could you explain, which ways there are for hiding documents from users to avoid confusion (no security issue if the user should still stumble upon such a document)?

Comment: I've updated my answer.